# Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS x64 only shows 2GB memory

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ram

Ubuntu only shows 2GB of my 6GB memory, BIOS and lshw reports it as having 6GB.
But free -m and top only sees 2GB.

Appreciate your help.

lshw output

```
   *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 28
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 6GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: CM3X2G1333C9
             vendor: Corsair
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: CHANNEL A
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: CM3X2G1333C9
             vendor: Corsair
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: CHANNEL A
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 9905474-051.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 2
             serial: 382CE993
             slot: CHANNEL B
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber3
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer3
             physical id: 3
             serial: A1_SerNum3
             slot: CHANNEL B
             width: 64 bits
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost definitely a compatibility issue. You have two 1333MHz cards and one 1600MHz card.

In theory this can work by downclocking the 1600 but this can cause issues.

**Secondly**  your board wants to run dual channel, so you need to fill either **2** or **4** slots not **3**.

I would take out the Kingston 1600MHz stick and try with just the other two. Make sure they are correctly placed (not necessarily next to each other, put them in the same colour slots).

If this works and gives you 4GB RAM, then you can try to fill the other two, a matching Kingston stick with he current Kingston stick may work, but everything matching is best.

If it will show 4GB RAM, then you can also try and take out the cards and put the 1600MHz to see if it's not dead or something.